# Dynamically assign "TABLES table_wa." to a structure

Tags: abap, dynpro

In my `/XXX/MY_FUNCTION_GROUP` function group include - `/XXX/MY_FUNCTION_GROUPTOP` - there's a table work area defined like this:
(see [syntax](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abaptables.htm))

```
FUNCTION-POOL /XXX/MY_FUNCTION_GROUP.

TABLES /xxx/my_structure.
```

My problem is that depending on the SAP system in which this program is imported the structure `/xxx/my_structure` may not exist which would lead to a syntax error.

Is there a way to make the structure dynamic?

---

So far I tried this, but that syntax is invalid:

```
TABLES ( '/xxx/my_structure' ).
```

Comment: It's not possible but you can find many workarounds depending on your context/needs. First questions: is "TABLES X" really necessary or can you use the dynamic variant of "DATA X TYPE X" instead? (TABLES required for some Dynpro features, Logical Database, memory sharing) Why is it needed to compile the program although running it would badly fail? Can't you define transport routes to force some objects to go in different transport requests? (assign these objects to dedicated Packages -> to Transport Layers)

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I haven't missed anything before analyzing possible workarounds - but it's clear now that there's no way around it :) therefore you answered the question for me - thanks! You can post that comment as an answer if you like.

Comment: Oh - and to clear up the question why it is needed to compile it even though running it would still fail: I just dumbed down the problem to the essence of what I'm asking. I wouldn't have left that string hardcoded in there - it would've been dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no dynamic variant of [`TABLES`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptables.htm).

But you can find many workarounds depending on your context/needs.

Questions you could ask yourself to help you find these workarounds:

- Is "`TABLES X`" really necessary or can you use the dynamic variant of "`DATA X TYPE X`" ([`CREATE DATA`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcreate_data.htm)) instead? `TABLES` is required for some Dynpro features, Logical Database, memory sharing.
- Why is it needed to compile the program although running it would badly fail?
- Can't you define transport routes to force objects to go in different transport requests? (assign these objects to dedicated Packages -> to Transport Layers)